# multidimension Arrays and Listboxes (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.Net and feel a bit confused about something.
I want to have two list boxes, in each ones I already have items. In my first list box I have 4 items, in my second List box I have 5 items. I have also added a text box, for the value I want to be stored in the array.

For example: if I select the first value of the first text box, and the second value of the second text box and type "5" in the text box, 5 will be stored in (0,1) of the array.

I then want all the values for each item of my first list box to be displayed in a label, same for the second items, third item, and fourth item. I suppose I would need a loop for this.

I know how to create an array, and how to store values in an array, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work using list boxes and a text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a form with the following controls:

```
ComboBox1  
ComboBox2  
Button1  
TextBox1
```

I've added code to the Form_Load and Button1_Click events and created a single ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event handler to deal with both combo boxes index changes.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _array(,) As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ReDim _array(0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count, 0 To ComboBox2.Items.Count)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim c1 As Integer = If(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1, 0, ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        Dim c2 As Integer = If(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1, 0, ComboBox2.SelectedIndex)
        Debug.Print(String.Format("Set ({0},{1}) to {2}", c1, c2, TextBox1.Text))
        _array(c1, c2) = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim c1 As Integer = If(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1, 0, ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        Dim c2 As Integer = If(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1, 0, ComboBox2.SelectedIndex)
        Debug.Print(String.Format("Get ({0},{1}) to {2}", c1, c2, TextBox1.Text))
        TextBox1.Text = _array(c1, c2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I'm demonstrating is that:
1. the array is resized when the form is loaded to match the number of elements in your comboboxes.
2. the data is loaded into the array on an event (in this case the button click event).
3. Retrieving the data again as either of the combo boxes changes.

Hope that helps.